# How to remove a drive from a storage pool on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, powershell, storage-spaces

I have 3 drives in a Storage Space on Windows 8. I am running a two way mirror. The drives are 2x2TB and 1x1TB. I want to remove the 1TB drive without replacing it. In other words, I only want the 2x2TB drives. How do I do this / is this possible to remove a drive without putting a new drive in its place? There is no "remove button" in the GUI, and I am not familiar with Powershell commands.

Comment: Don't think it's possible without breaking and rebuilding the array. See [this forum thread](http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1709394) for example.

Answer (score 1):

As long as all your storage spaces have parity or mirroring just remove the drive. If you have any simple storage spaces you will want to copy that data to a new storage space with resiliency and then remove the drive. The storage space status should then show a missing driving and allow you to select remove link.